# Are the two sets equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the following statement True for any sets A and B?
$$(A\setminus B)^\complement= A^\complement\setminus B^\complement$$

Attempt:

1. Let $x\in (A\setminus B)^\complement$. Then, $x\notin A\setminus B$. So, $x\notin A$ and $x\in B$.
2. Let $x\in A^\complement\setminus B^\complement$. Then, $x\in A^\complement$ and $x\notin B^\complement$. So, $x\notin A$ and $x \in B$.

So, this is a true statement. But the Venn diagram I drew says different. So maybe the attempt was wrong.

**Note**: $A^\complement$ is complement of $A$ and $A\setminus B$ is the set difference between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "x not in A\B => x not in A and x in B"?

Comment: Take $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$ as subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$.  Now compare.

Comment: Please write the post in a readable way. Use "\setminus" instead of "\"

Comment: use counter example take some set for A and B

Comment: Take your Venn Diagram, put some letters in each of the regions, then use those letters to create some finite sets $A$ and $B$. Use these insights to structure your proof.

Comment: The mistake in your proof is that $x \in (A \setminus B)^c \iff (x\in A \land x\in B)$ or $x \notin A$

Comment: @ Calvin Lin I think by definition, A\B = {x: x in A and x not in B}, so if x not in A\B, wouldn't that mean {x:x not in A and x in B}?

Comment: @IcedTea If something is NOT (in A but also NOT in B), could it ever be in A? Naively speaking, the "NOT in A" suggests that it couldn't be, but you're forgetting the "but also NOT B" part. IE Is an element that is in A and in B, going to be part of this set?

Comment: @MichealHoppe I see, they are different, that means the statement is False.

Comment: Ok.. so x not in A\B means x not in A or x in B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , you should know that $A \setminus B$ = $A \cap B^c$ and $ (A \cap B)^c$=$A^c \cup B^c$ i.e you can think it like de -morgans law.

so,$(A \setminus B)^c =A \cup B^c$ but ,$A^c \setminus B^c=A^c \cap B$

so, It is false statement

Comment: What is the de-morgan law?

Comment: @IcedTea https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#:~:text=In%20propositional%20logic%20and%20Boolean,both%20valid%20rules%20of%20inference.&text=The%20rules%20allow%20the%20expression,of%20each%20other%20via%20negation.

Answer (score 0):

A counter example:

Let $A, B \subset X$. and let $A=B;$

LHS: $(A$ \ $ A) ^c=(\emptyset) ^c=X;$

RHS:: $A^c $ \  $A^c=\emptyset;$

A contradition